# how to add styles for custom leaflet popup

Tags: angular, leaflet, marker, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to add styling of marker popup but styles are not reflecting on popup.
Also not able to add priming button.

```js
import { Map, marker} from "leaflet";

const popupOptions = { className: "customPopup" };
const template = "<div>Class</div>" + "<div>undefined</div>" +
      '<button  class="edit" id="buttonEdit" type="button">Edit</button>';
      
const markerLayer = marker([latitute, longitute], {
      icon: icon({
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [13, 41],
        iconUrl: imageURL
      })
    }).bindPopup(template, popupOptions);
map.addLayer(markerLayer);
```

```css
.customPopup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper .leaflet-popup-content{
  width: 251px;
}

.customPopup 
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper 
.leaflet-popup-content
.edit{
  color: #fefefe;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the documentation you can pass to `bindPopup` (String | HTMLElement | Function | Popup content, options) - [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer-bindpopup)

In my example, I pass

```
const customPopup = '<input type="text">';
```

And the options and `className` in it can be used to control the appearance of the popup.

```
const customOptions = {
 'maxWidth': 'auto', // set max-width
 'className': 'customPopup' // name custom popup
}
```

And now it is enough to pass these two options to the `bindPopup` marker.

```
L.marker([lat, lon])
  .bindPopup(customPopup, customOptions)
  .addTo(map);
```

```js
/**
 * Custom marker and popup
 */

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZomm: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 50.0619474;
const lon = 19.9368564;

// calling map
const map = L.map('map', config).setView([lat, lon], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


const funny = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://grzegorztomicki.pl/serwisy/pin.png',
  iconSize: [50, 58], // size of the icon
  iconAnchor: [20, 58], // changed marker icon position
  popupAnchor: [0, -60] // changed popup position
});


// create popup contents
const customPopup = '<input type="text">';

// specify popup options  
const customOptions = {
  'maxWidth': 'auto', // set max-width
  'className': 'customPopup' // name custom popup
}

// create marker object, pass custom icon as option, pass content and options to popup, add to map
L.marker([lat, lon], {
    icon: funny
  })
  .bindPopup(customPopup, customOptions)
  .addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.customPopup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.customPopup .leaflet-popup-tip {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

I prepared a basic set of examples using leaflet - [leaflet-examples](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples) maybe something will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

What `layer` are you trying to attach the popup to?  You need to define some `layer` to attach the popup to.

The rest of your code works fine.  For example, if you attach your popup to an `L.Marker`, it works fine.

### [Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-with-custom-css-y7vie)

You might want to look into what [L.Layer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer) is.  Many of the other layertype in Leaflet are extensions of `L.Layer`.  You have to attach your popup to something that falls in that category.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a quick reply. I am trying to add on marker layer only, but its not working for me. I have updated code.

Comment: I updated my codesandbox to look more like your code, but I am still not able to replicate your issue.  Its working well in the csb.  Can you post a sandbox or codepen demonstrating the problem?

Comment: its the same what you are doing its just I am using google maps, don't know why its not working for me.

Comment: google maps?  i feel like there's a whole bunch of code going on that we are not seeing.  The code you posted should work.  what are we missing here?

Comment: I have created custom Component and passed that to bind pop, it resolved all problem and now I can customize button and layout as per need.